# Update app.get response with data from http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using **express** and passing path as an url parameter.

```
app.get("/download", function (req, res) {
    var location;
    var options = {
        host: 'example.com',
        port: 80,
        path: req.query.url.replace(/ /g, "%20")
    };

    http.get(options, function (res) {

        // get location from this 

        location = res.headers.location;
        console.log(location);

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });

    // it won't get the location data since http.get is async
    // so how could I send this response using the data from http.get

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(location);
});
```

In this code I want the data retrieve from request headers of **http.get** to be used for rendering on the browser.

Is there anyway that I could do to render the **http.get** data on the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just move the `res.send()` inside the function e.g:

```
app.get("/download", function (req, res) {
    var location;
    var options = {
        host: 'example.com',
        port: 80,
        path: req.query.url.replace(/ /g, "%20")
    };

    http.get(options, function (response) {

        // get location from this 

        location = response.headers.location;
        console.log(location);

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.send(location);

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        res.send('Error...')
    });

});
```

I'd also suggest using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package for making HTTP requests as it can make the whole process simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from the 'GET' query to `example.com` through the use of middleware. The middleware will intercept any requests to the app, perform any actions defined within it and pass control back to the handler for that request.

```
// Define middleware that makes a 'GET' request to 'example.com' and obtains the location.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var options = {
      host: 'example.com',
      port: 80,
      path: req.query.url.replace(/ /g, "%20")
  };

  http.get(options, function (res) {

      // Attach the location to the request object. This will be present
      // in the request object of the 'GET' handler for the app.
      req.webLocation = res.headers.location;

      // Execute the next middleware or the route handler if there's no
      // other middleware.
      next();

  }).on('error', function (e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  });
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    // Render the 'webLocation' obtained from the middleware.
    res.send(req.webLocation);
});
```